# Error in Azure Quota Request Status - List call

Tags: azure, azure-rest-api

If I add the `$filter` paramenter with the value `"requestSubmitTime ge 2021-05-16T09:00:00Z"` parameter to the [Quota Request Status - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/reserved-vm-instances/quotarequeststatus/list) call, I get the following error:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ParameterMalformed",
    "message": "Failed to parse expression: Syntax error at position 28 in 'requestSubmitTime ge 2021-05-16T09:00:00Z'.",
    "target": "$filter"
  }
}
```

Position 28 is in the middle of the ISO 6108 standard formatted date. So, what could here be the problem?

This is how the call looks like:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Capacity/resourceProviders/Microsoft.Compute/locations/northeurope/serviceLimitsRequests?api-version=2020-10-25&%24filter=requestSubmitTime%20ge%202021-05-16T09%3A00%3A00Z
Authorization: Bearer {token}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please specify your filter criteria like the following:

```
requestSubmitTime ge datetimeoffset'2021-05-16T09:00:00.000Z'
```

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Capacity/resourceProviders/Microsoft.Compute/locations/northeurope/serviceLimitsRequests?api-version=2020-10-25&%24filter=requestSubmitTime%20ge%20datetimeoffset'2021-05-16T09%3A00%3A00Z'
Authorization: Bearer {token}
```

And your request should work just fine.